# Android Show Fragment Over Activity Actionbar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

**Fragment shows below Activity Actionbar, I want to show Fragment Over
Activity Actionbar**

**My Requirement**

[image]

**Activity that have Fragment**

[image]

**On Menu OverFlow I show Fragment**

**I want to Show Show Fragment Over Activity Action bar, see Image bellow**

[image]

Comment: use actionbar sherlock

Comment: I am Using ActionBar.OnNavigationListener for < handling previous Activity

Answer (score 2):

use Sliding menu or Navigation Drawer or follow below links

[android-sliding-menu](http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/android-sliding-menu-demo/)

or [android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 0):

The final Solution is Navigation Drawer or Fragment not Showing on Action Bar